# Read from terminal without waiting for [ENTER]

Tags: terminal, user-input

I'm sorry to bother you with such silly questions, but I recently started working with the Linux terminal and when I was reading a paper about the command `stty` I found the following question:

> ¿How can you change the echo and read without waiting for <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (simply by entering a hexadecimal digit from "0" to "f")?

I know that the first part `stty -echo` and `stty echo`.

But I have no clue of how to do read from terminal without waiting for <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
I have been searching in the `man` the second one and I cannot find in the command `stty` the settings to make this posible.

I know it should be something simple but I can't find a solution or logic to the addition of entering a hexadecimal digit.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to read -- the shell builtin, then it has an option to return after reading N characters rather than waiting for ENTER. Try:

```
read -n1 ; echo You entered $REPLY
```

Also, `read --help`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, is that the terminal device driver (the kernel code behind the `/dev/tty*` or `/dev/pt*` device, not the physical device with a keyboard and monitor you interact with) implements a basic line editor.

When an application does a `read()` system call on a file descriptor open on `/dev/pts/0` for instance, that `read()` only returns with the full content of the line you've entered (and possibly edited with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>...) when you press enter (and with the CR character sent by your terminal when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> converted to LF).

To disable that line editor you need to issue specific control instructions to that device driver. And that's where the `stty` command comes into play.

With `stty -icanon`, that line editor is disabled (`stty cbreak` was needed on some systems instead and you'll find `stty cbreak` is often supported as an alternative).

When not in that `icanon` mode, some other parameters are used to customise that *direct* mode:

- `^C`, `^Z` are still causing interrupt/suspend. And you'd need `stty -isig` to disable them so they're passed as-is to the reading application.
- `^Q`, `^S` are still used for flow control (`stty -ixon` to disable).
- `CR` is still converted to `LF`, and you'd need `stty -icrnl` to disable it.

`stty raw` is a shortcut to disable all of those and some of the *output* processing as well. If on top of that, you add a `-echo`, then your `/dev/pts/1` device acts like a plain pass-through between your terminal and the application interacting with it.

So:

```
saved_settings=$(stty -g)
stty raw -echo
byte=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null)
stty "$saved_settings"
```

Will ready exactly one *byte* (not character, let alone the sequence of character that your terminal may send upon some key press) from the terminal device as soon as it's send by your terminal.

Except in ksh (when the `vi`/`emacs`/`gmacs` options are on where ksh implements its own line editor, see `vared` in `zsh` or `read -e` in bash for an equivalent) the `read` builtin by default doesn't change the terminal device settings, so will still have to wait for <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get anything from the terminal device.

However the `read` builtin of zsh (with the `-k` or `-q` options) and that of ksh93, bash or mksh (with the `-n` or `-N` options) will disable that `icanon` mode to be able to return on a single keypress when they get their input from a terminal device (`isig` is not disabled though so you can still interrupt a script with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> for instance).